Layer 2 WiFi-Eth Bridge Not Forwarding DHCP Requests
I’m running Ubuntu 64-bit Server on a Raspberry Pi 4B. I have a USB-WiFi dongle with WDS/4addr/AP mode enabled that is connected to my gateway. I then have a Layer 2 Bridge setup using iproute2 that includes this WiFi dongle and the Pi’s Ethernet port (eth0).
In theory, I’d like Ethernet clients to be able to connect to the internet (via Ethernet->WiFi Card->gateway) and other devices on the network (multicast/AirPlay).
I plugged a Sonos speaker into the Ethernet jack and I can see the device in my list of AirPlay devices on my iPhone. I can also see its MAC address on the Pi. The Sonos speaker is sending a DHCP request but is not receiving an IP address from the router even though I have Ip forwarding on on the RPi. I’ve tried adding dhcp relay/other libraries that could help forward this request but it still doesn’t seem to be working. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix?

Just to be clear, can you confirm that your gateway supports WDS and that you configured that gateway's WDS feature to know about the Pi's WDS interface? Have you verified that WDS packets are flowing in both directions?

Apologies, am realizing I never answered this. I can successfully connect the WiFi card to the gateway while in 4addr mode, and connect to the internet
